# Unir dos modelos en asp.net mvc 5 c# - N CAPAS

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

Tengo dos modelos:

```
public class TipoSolicitudesDTO
{
    [Key]
    public int TipoSolicitudID { get; set; }
    public string NombreTipoSolicitud { get; set; }
    public int EstadoTipoSolicitud { get; set; }       
}

public class SolicitudesDTO
{
    [Key]
    public int SolicitudID { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaEmision { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaFin { get; set; }
    public string Observacion { get; set; }
    public int Estado { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TipoSolicitudID { get; set; }        
}
```

es una relacion de 1 a *.

```
public List<SolicitudesDTO> ObtenerSolicitudes(int id)
    {
        //Se crea la lista que se enviara como resultado.
        List<SolicitudesDTO> lista = new List<SolicitudesDTO>();
        //Se instancia la conexion de datos
        using (SqlConnection conn = ConexionDAL.ConexionSQL())
        {
            // se setea el comando que define el procedimiento almacenado y conexion a utilizar para obtener los datos desde la bd.
            using (SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("ListarPermisos", conn))
            {
                comando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

                //Se instancia el adapter, que sirve para ejecutar el comando.
                using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(comando))
                {
                    DataTable tbResultados = new DataTable();

                    //ejecuto el comando utilizando el adapter y lleno la tabla con los datos obtenidos.
                    adap.Fill(tbResultados);

                    //si se lograron extraer datos entonces agregare todos los objetos a la lista.
                    if (tbResultados.Rows.Count > 0 || tbResultados.Rows != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < tbResultados.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            DataRow fila = tbResultados.Rows[i];
                            SolicitudesDTO Solicitud = new SolicitudesDTO();                                
                            Solicitud.SolicitudID = Convert.ToInt32(fila["SolicitudID"]);
                            Solicitud.FechaEmision = Convert.ToDateTime(fila["FechaEmision"]);
                            Solicitud.FechaInicio = Convert.ToDateTime(fila["FechaInicio"]);
                            Solicitud.FechaFin = Convert.ToDateTime(fila["FechaFin"]);
                            Solicitud.Observacion = Convert.ToString(fila["Observacion"]);
                            Solicitud.Estado = Convert.ToInt32(fila["Estado"]);
                            Solicitud.Id = Convert.ToInt32(fila["Id"]);
                            Solicitud.TipoSolicitudID = Convert.ToInt32(fila["TipoSolicitudID"]);     
                            lista.Add(Solicitud);
                        }
                    }
                }//FIN ADAPTER
            }//FIN COMANDO
        }//FIN CONEXION

        return lista;
    }
```

Solo se esta llenando la **clase Solicitudes** como agrego la **clase TipoSolicitudes** para tambien llenarlo desde mi SP ??

ListarPermisos : Es un el siguiente inner join en sql server

```
    create proc ListarPermisos
    @id int
    as
    SELECT * FROM tipoSolicitudes
    INNER JOIN Solicitudes ON tiposolicitudes.TipoSolicitudID= solicitudes.TipoSolicitudID 
where id=@id
```

Comment: Por lo que veo en el código solo estás leyendo un solo registro así que para el Tipo Solicitud haces lo que mismo que para leer Solicitud. Instancia un objeto TIpoSolicitud y lee las columnas que corresponda a TipoSolicitud

Comment: Efectivamente estaba mal el codigo, ya lo modifique , mi consulta es si instancio el TipoSolicitud como deberia agregar a **lista** si lista solo es para solicitudes ???

Comment: Que datos tiene la tabla tiposolicitud?

Comment: **TipoSolicitudesDTO** TipoSolicitudID, NombreTipoSolicitud, EstadoTipoSolicitud ,solo lo necesito para obtener el nombre de la solicitud.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo. TipoSolicitud tiene (Tipo 1, Tipo 2, Tipo 3,....) y Solicitudes tiene algo como ({Solicitud 1, Tipo 1}, {Solicitud 1, Tipo 2}, {Solicitud 2, Tipo 1},.....)

Comment: Coloca ejemplo de los datos que tienen las tablas solicitudes y tipos

Comment: En TipoSolicitudes ("Permiso de Vacaciones",1) 1 es el area RRHH, Solicitudes (agrego la fecha de la solicitude de vacaciones, de que fecha a que fecha)

Answer (score -1):

Como interpreto los Data Transfer Object (DTO), es que un TipoSolicitudes puede tener MUCHAS  Solicitudes.

Por lo cual te recomiendo modificar el DTO, Solicitudes:

```
public class SolicitudesDTO
{
    [Key]
    public int SolicitudID { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaEmision { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaFin { get; set; }
    public string Observacion { get; set; }
    public int Estado { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TipoSolicitudesDTO TipoSolicitud {get;set;}
}
```

Así mismo al momento de llenar los datos (En la instrucción, for), debes probar lo siguiente:

```
               for (int i = 0; i < tbResultados.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DataRow fila = tbResultados.Rows[i];
                        SolicitudesDTO Solicitud = new SolicitudesDTO();                                
                        Solicitud.SolicitudID = Convert.ToInt32(fila["SolicitudID"]);
                        Solicitud.FechaEmision = Convert.ToDateTime(fila["FechaEmision"]);
                        Solicitud.FechaInicio = Convert.ToDateTime(fila["FechaInicio"]);
                        Solicitud.FechaFin = Convert.ToDateTime(fila["FechaFin"]);
                        Solicitud.Observacion = Convert.ToString(fila["Observacion"]);
                        Solicitud.Estado = Convert.ToInt32(fila["Estado"]);
                        Solicitud.Id = Convert.ToInt32(fila["Id"]);
                        Solicitud.TipoSolicitudID = new TipoSolicitudesDTO()
                        {
                            TipoSolicitudID = Convert.ToInt32(fila["TipoSolicitudID"]),
                            NombreTipoSolicitud  = Convert.ToString(fila["NombreTipoSolicitud"]),
                            EstadoTipoSolicitud = Convert.ToInt32(fila["EstadoTipoSolicitud"])
                        }
                        lista.Add(Solicitud);
                    }
```

Sin embargo no es recomendable, debido que tendrá tipos de solicitudes repetidos (Ya que una solicitud puede tener muchos tipos de solicitudes).

Comment: Gracias, @diego orellana entonces cual seria lo recomendable?

Comment: Así mismo existe framework (Orientado a ORM), que te puede facilitar el trabajo, tal como [Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/)

Comment: @LuisVega lo recomendable es que TipoSolicitudesDTO tenga una lista (O diccionario)  de SolicitudesDTO, y empieces llenando el objeto padre y posteriormente los hijos.

Comment: Concuerdo con @diego orellana si no quieres que se repitan utiliza un diccionario.

Comment: voy a investigar como usar un diccionario,si huviera la posiblidad que me ayuden con un ejemplo de mis tablas usando diccionario les agradecera.

Comment: Se da una respuesta y al final escribes que no es recomendable?